# Disapointed by Vertx versus raw servlet

Tags: performance, servlets, vert.x

Vertx is way slower than raw asyncservlet with exactly the same code to execute

I have implemented a very basic GET http method that does nothing than Thread.sleep(30) before returning http response text "ok". I did this with jetty-servlet and vertx-verticles

```
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

    DeploymentOptions d = new DeploymentOptions();
    d.setInstances(400);
    d.setWorker(true);
    d.setWorkerPoolSize(400);
    vertx.deployVerticle("com.vertx.Ping",d);
```

public class Ping extends AbstractVerticle {

```
private HttpServer server;

public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) {

    server = vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(req -> {
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(30);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        req.response().end("ok");
    });

    server.listen(9999);

}
```

}

ab -k -c 1 -n 1 => same result for servlet and vertx : ~31ms

Servlet: ab -k -c 1000 -n 100000
Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    219
  66%    224
  75%    227
  80%    229
  90%    235
  95%    240
  98%    245
  99%    247
 100%    264 (longest request)

Vertx: ab -k -c 1000 -n 100000 => after more than 2 minutes i stopped the test

Let's try something easier : 
Vertx: ab -k -c 1000 -n 10000 (10 times less)

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%   3930
  66%   3943
  75%   3964
  80%   3977
  90%   3997
  95%   4009
  98%   4019
  99%   4028
 100%   4038 (longest request)

Vertx is so damn slow, what do i do wrong folks ? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You are not using Vert.x as it should be. Remember that Vert.x is based on asynchronous operations.

First off, you don't need 400 worker verticle instances. Just 1 regular (non-worker) verticle instance is more than enough. You are doing this because you call `Thread.sleep`, which causes a thread to block, but there is a much simpler way.

Next: don't use blocking operations! You are running code on an event-loop, so you must not block. Your code should look like:

```
vertx
  .createHttpServer()
  .requestHandler(req -> {
    vertx.setTimer(30, tid -> {
      req.response().end("ok");
    }
  })
  .listen(9999);
```

You should see a drastic improvement in your measures, and all of that with just 1 thread compared to the 400 you had.

Note: when you need to call a blocking operation, you should have a look at `executeBlocking` in the `Vertx` class, which offloads some code to a worker, and then dispatches the result as a new event.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will test the code you provided. That being said i'm sure my code was running on the worker pool because i didn't get any error message from vertx complaingin about blocking the event loop...I let you know !